# CubesViewer Server not always loading cubes

Tags: python, mysql, olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm using CubesViewer server on my machine (with linux) and I followed all the instruction on github (https://github.com/jjmontesl/cubesviewer).

I'm using a mysql database to create cubes and they are perfect (using the command "curl", I can see the cubes working and also I can see them using the application) .

The application can work 24/7 but it can't load the cubes after a few hours of usage and I don't know why. The only thing that works is restarting the application but I want to found another solution (easier I hope).

Can someone help me?

Comment: This really depends on your setup. CubesViewer server is a Django app and should be able to run 24/7. Is the whole app down or is it just cubes it cannot load? what web server are you using? does the webserver logs show any error? what error does the client Javascript console show?

Comment: In addition, I use `processes: 6` in my environment inside the `[server]` section of the `slicer.ini` file. You might try that just in case.

Comment: @jjmontes cubes can't load the data but the application it's not down. Thanks, I will try

Comment: @jjmontes it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jjmontes, I added `processes: 6` in my environment inside the `[server]` section of the `slicer.ini` file and now it's working!